# C++ Why can't I call a funtion in my class

Tags: c++, class

How can I get this code to work?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
TestClass testclass;
int number = testclass.AddNumbers(3, 5);

cout << number << endl;
return 0;
}
```

TestClass.h

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H 


class TestClass
{
    public:
        TestClass();
        int AddNumbers(int num1, int num2);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // TESTCLASS_H
```

TestClass.cpp

```
#include "TestClass.h"

TestClass::TestClass(){

}

int TestClass::AddNumbers(int num1, int num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

The only error I get is "Undefined reference to TestClass::TestClass()
and "Undefined reference to TestClass::AddNumbers(int, int)".

Comment: How are you compiling this? Are you sure TestClass.cpp was compiled ?

Comment: Most likely you have not added  TestClass.cpp to your project.

Comment: You're right, Captain!

Answer (score 2):

When you're compiling two .cpp files, you will get as a result two "object files". These are intermediate files containing the compiled content. After that, you need to link them to the actual executable binary.

Have a look at the link Captain Oblivous provided and check out the second answer. It explains this in greater deep.

Comment: I really don't understand this answer. I'm very new to c++ and I'm working in Code::Blocks so I don't know what settings I would have to change for this to work.

Comment: Check that both .cpp files are in the actual project, so Code::Blocks will link them.

Comment: I added them twice, and it still did not compile. Is my code wrong in any way?

Comment: ***Is my code wrong in any way?*** Your code does not look wrong to me.

Comment: Your code is not wrong, but your project is, since it seems not to link the generated code of Testclass.cpp. Check your project settings.